# computed property must have an explicit type while using didSet

Tags: xcode, swift

```
var number = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.updateScore()
      }
}
```

After writing this code  a failure appears: computed property must have an explicit type. I believe it`s a problem with my version of Xcode (6.2), cause at my friends computer compiles perfectly. What should I change, so that it works on mine?

Comment: What version is your friend on and is there any particular reason you're not updating to Xcode 6.3.2?

Comment: Well, it's not a problem to specify a type like `var number: Int = 0` is it?

Comment: Thank you Alladinan, it works! I implemented it wrongly.